# The same formula performed on two different versions of Mathematica yields different results. [Life is so tough]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerical-integration, numerics, numerical-value

Let me show the code first.

```
 Gama[kx_, ky_, u_] := NIntegrate[96*Cos[p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(-7/2)*1/(
6!*Sqrt[Pi])*(((Sqrt[2*u]/(
       Cos[p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2)))^6 + 
     15/2*(Sqrt[2*u]/(
        Cos[p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2)))^4 + 
     45/4*(Sqrt[2*u]/(
        Cos[p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2)))^2 + 15/
     8)*Sqrt[Pi]*
   Exp[(Sqrt[2*u]/(
      Cos[p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2)))^2]*
   Erfc[Sqrt[2*u]/(
    Cos[p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2))] - (Sqrt[
    2*u]/(Cos[p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2)))^5 - 
  7*(Sqrt[2*u]/(
     Cos[p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2)))^3 - 
  33/4*(Sqrt[2*u]/(
    Cos[p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2)))), {p, -Pi, 
Pi}];
```

Then  you can use

```
 Plot[Gama[0, 0, u], {u, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

You may find that the values are very large.[image]

Then I try another computer, I get
[image]

These days,   I am really lucky.   Life is tough!

Comment: Those two graphs look the same to me.  What are we looking for?

Comment: see  Fig1   and Fig3         @ChrisK

Comment: Here I upload three figures.   The last two figures are the same.   I do not know how to delete one of them.

Comment: I removed it for you. Could you tell us the results of ```FullForm@N[Im[Erfc[(1.0` I)]]]``` on both machines and also `$MachinePrecision` and
`$MachineEpsilon` and `$Version` and
`$SystemWordLength` for both machines please.

Comment: the result of    FullForm@N[Im[Erfc[(1.0  I)]]]  is -1.6504257587975428.     These two versions gives the same result.@flinty

Comment: Can you still provide `$Version` and `$SystemWordLength` here for both machines - I need to rule out something.

Comment: @Blueka Haha, thanks, I thought it was one of those "spot the differences" puzzles!

Comment: @flinty     version:11.3.0.0            11.2.0.0

Comment: @Blueka okay, and $SystemWordLength  ?

Comment: @flinty    $SystemWordLength      both of them are 64

Comment: @flinty Do you install the above two versions? If convenient, you can control my pc.

Comment: @Blueka The same result I got with versions 12.0.0 (your first picture) and 12.1.1 (your second picture). It means that result is unstable. We can check it just call `Table[{u, Gama[0., 0., u]}, {u, .0, 1., .1}]`. There are pole at `p=Pi/2` and `p=-Pi/2`. So we should use some strategy to compute this integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a question of numerical precision.

Set ky and ky to zero and plot the integrand ii, enlarge working precision and rationalize variable in Plot.

```
ii[p_, u_] = 
96*Cos[p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(-7/2)*1/(6!*
   Sqrt[Pi])*(((Sqrt[
         2*u]/(Cos[
           p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2)))^6 + 
     15/2*(Sqrt[
          2*u]/(Cos[
            p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2)))^4 + 
     45/4*(Sqrt[
          2*u]/(Cos[
            p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2)))^2 + 
     15/8)*Sqrt[Pi]*
   Exp[(Sqrt[
        2*u]/(Cos[p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2)))^2]*
   Erfc[Sqrt[
      2*u]/(Cos[
        p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2))] - (Sqrt[
      2*u]/(Cos[p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2)))^5 - 
  7*(Sqrt[2*
        u]/(Cos[p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2)))^3 - 
  33/4*(Sqrt[
      2*u]/(Cos[
        p/2]*(1 + I*kx*Cos[p] + I*ky*Sin[p])^(1/2)))) /. {kx -> 0,
 ky -> 0} // Simplify[#, -Pi < p < Pi && 0 < u < 1] &

Plot3D[ii[p, u], {p, -Pi, Pi}, {u, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, .1}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 30]

Ga00[u_] := NIntegrate[ii[p, u], {p, -Pi, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]

Plot[Ga00[Rationalize[u, 0]], {u, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Cool!    Thanks!     I get the point.